# Cannot $push item into array with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use a POST request to add an item into a collection within a user object.

```
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"_id": req.body.userid}, 
    {$push: {'shopping_list': req.body.itemid}},
    {safe: true, upsert: true},
    function(err, Model){
      console.log(err, Model);
      if(err){
        handleError(res, err);
      }
      return res.status(201).json(Model);
    }
  );
```

I keep getting the following error:

> {"name":"MongoError","message":"exception: '$push' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$push: {: ...}}","value":{"_id":"5546cc0483b0186428e252cc","email":"lilly@test.com","passwordHash":"Q+VpK9L+I/DhAm7w01AArMacBkXEdyHp3zGF6JyJVzDhwgHpws4z8IBxycI7xrRX6Do2AEe/BvI37HauvAc6WA==","salt":"0Bi6XW0YuxutizQY3PZH4Q==","budget":5000,"shopping_list":[],"cupboard":[],"meals":[],"__v":0},"errmsg":"exception: '$push' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$push: {: ...}}","code":9,"ok":0}

I can't see why that's happening as the field 'shopping_list' is clearly visible and a value is passed...

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Is `shopping_list` in the schema definition for `User`?

Comment: *shame mode* I commented it out whilst fixing another bug... :D If you add it as the answer, I'll accept it... Thanks @JohnnyHK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, Mongoose won't update fields that do not appear in your model's schema.

So either add `shopping_list` to your schema or set the [`strict`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) option on the schema to `false`.

Comment: This gave me a really good idea what the problem was in my case. Thanks